# Register.php not inserting sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have been trying to create a register.php i have tried at least 17 methods but they do not work :(
I even used a bunch of scripts and more but still nothing :( 
What is the problem?

```
<!-- Start header.php -->
<?php include_once ('includes/header.php'); ?>
<!-- End header.php -->
<!-- Start navbar -->
<?php include_once ('includes/navbar.php'); ?>
<!-- End navbar -->
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query =  "INSERT INTO `users` (`userID` ,`username` ,`password` ,`email` ,`avatar` ,`signup_date` ,`firstname` ,`lastname` ,`relations` ,`sex` ,`hometown` ,`skype` ,`facebook` ,`emailp` ,`twitter` ,`website` ,`about`)
VALUES ('', '".$username."', '".$password."', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
?>
<div class="wrapper row4">
  <div id="container" class="clear">
         <h1>Register - <small>Please fill out the form to register.</small></h1>
         <form method="post">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="usn">Username : </label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" />
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="passwd">Password : </label>
                            <input type="password"   name="password" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="buttons">
                            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </form>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include_once ('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Anything wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: Try adding error checking.  `if($result === FALSE){ die(mysql_error()); }`.  Also, do you ever actually connect to your database?  P.S. Don't use this code on a real website, it's very unsafe.

Comment: Yes i'm connecting to a database this is just a test to see and make it work :)

Comment: Just got a error : " Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'userID' at row 1"

Comment: Well, there ya go.  Is `userID` set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  Try using `NULL` instead of `''`.  In fact, just set the fields you need, you don't need to set them all: `INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')`.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if `userID` field is set as autoincrement:

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO `users` (`username` ,`password` ,`email` ,`avatar` ,`signup_date` ,`firstname` ,`lastname` ,`relations` ,`sex` ,`hometown` ,`skype` ,`facebook` ,`emailp` ,`twitter` ,`website` ,`about`)
VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')";
```

Maybe your `userID` field don't accept null values...

Comment: Get this error when registering  "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'userID' at row 1" i know it's sql Auto-Increment Primary .

Comment: But in the query that i posted i dont put the userID field...check again pls